# Engineer condition removal upon kit equipement

Tags: guild-wars-2

Whenever I equip a kit with my engineer, I am able to remove a condition. This effect seems to trigger with a cooldown. But I can't seem to find where does this effect trigger from.

My weapons do not have specific sigils, nor my armour have runes. I've got 30 Firearms (IV, VIII, XI), 30 Alchemy (V, VII, IX) and 10 in Tools (IV).

The only traits that would be related to this effect are:

Alchemy IX Backpack Regenerator that gives regen when equipped with a kit, or the Tools IV  Kit refinement which cast a spell or attack upon equipping. I think the latter is the most probable source and that the effect is some kind of undocumented effect.

So, do condition removal comes from this trait?

EDIT: This works with Elixir Gun, Flamethrower for sure. Does not trigger with MedKit.

Comment: Which Kit in particular?

Comment: I edited the question to add the details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Kit Refinement trait, switching to the elixir gun will create a heal/condition removal field around you.

Comment: Sorry if I did not precised it, but this is triggering for at least FT and EG. So the field has nothing to do with the effect, and you do not have to shoot within the field to remove the conditions.

Comment: the field has an on activate effect (so when you trigger the ability you get the benefits immediately), and the the EG ability leaves behind a field that can be used. The FT also cleared conditions for me when testing it.

http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Kit_Refinement - These are apparently the effects caused by Kit Refinement - not sure exactly where the condition removal is coming from according to that list.